# Anyone concerned that, by individuals getting rich too fast, crime towards cryptocurrency holders will also increase?

Tags: theft, safety, wealth-distribution

Given the potential for such a gigantic paradigm shift, something so accessible and so global could displace enormous amounts of value to large groups of people that previously had very little capital. Not everybody may understand the underlaying technology and how to protect their assets making them easy targets for fraud or exploitation. It's everyone's responsibility to protect them selfs but it on the other side there will be equally or smarter people trying to gain access to their entries on the ledger.

I guess anyone has the ability to protect their wealth in the digital network, but I wonder if we will start seeing more cryptocurrency thefts in the more physical violence context (kidnapping to make someone release their private keys, hardware seizures,...).

Anyone thought of how this will have an impact in terms of crime in the coming 5 or 10 years? Is there going to be a lot of money to protect and a lot of incentive to steal it?

Comment: The title of the question does not really match it's content : Will crime raise due to cryptocurrency? What is your question exactly